# "Could Not Register User For Website Identifier web.com.WEBSITE, received response 404" error for safari push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, web-deployment

I've been trying to implement **Safari Push Notification** to my website, and it *kind of* works.
The versions I've tested are:

- 9 & 10 which goes to the V1 pushPackage endpoint (works)
- 11 & 12 which goes to the V2 pushPackage endpoint (works)
- 12.1 which *should* go to the V2 endpoint (does not work)

The pop up shows for each and every one of them (except 12.1), and I'm able to click allow (*verified manually to Safari settings, it changes to granted*). But, after that, the callback function does not run (based on my code below, it should log `ASKED` and after I click allow, `GRANTED`), it only log `ASKED`, and after I refresh the page, `GRANTED`. (*I'm able to print the device token*)

What's interesting is, before the refresh, it sends an error log to the

```
https://YOUR_API/v1/logs endpoint
```

(yes, even 11 & 12, which uses the V2 pushPackage ends up logging to the V1 error endpoint)

The error log says

> Could not register user for website identifier web.com.MYSITE,
>   received response 404

No idea what it means, it's not on Apple's documentation.

For reference, here's my code:

```
const checkRemotePermission = (permissionData) => {
   if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
      console.log('ASKED')
         window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
            'https://MYENDPOINT',
            'web.com.MYSITE',
            {},
            checkRemotePermission
         )
      } else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
           console.log('DENIED')
      } else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
           console.log('GRANTED')
      }
   }
   if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
      var permissionData = window.safari.pushNotification.permission('web.com.MYSITE')
      checkRemotePermission(permissionData)
   }
```

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When a user Registering, Updating or Forgetting device permission policy, a POST or DELETE request is sent to the following URL
webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceToken/registrations/websitePushID

So this URL must exist in order to avoid such error

The example URL will look like
https://yoursite.com/v1|v2/devices/75DA1C150840DAB9P7130022F4BF0F0638005B152C2D26B4B65FDAF5F7FDA19D/registrations/web.com.yoursite